# Import is ignored on require.js by migrating old AngularJS to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, requirejs, umd

I want to migrate my old AngularJS application from JavaScript to TypeScript.
For loading the requirements I'm using require.js. And because I want to be compatible with the non-require.js scripts I'm using `umd` as `module`.

For example I have this files.

**customModule.ts**

```
import angular = require('angular');

angular.module('customModule', []);
```

**main.ts**

```
import angular = require('angular');
import customModule = require('customModule');

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('customFactory', ['customModule', class {
        constructor(
            private customModule
        ) { }

        out() {
            return this.customModule;
        };
    }]);
```

This will be converted to this JavaScript.

**customModule.js**

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports", "angular"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var angular = require("angular");
    angular.module('customModule', []);
});
```

**main.ts**

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports", "angular"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var angular = require("angular");
    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('customFactory', ['customModule', (function () {
            function class_1(customModule) {
                this.customModule = customModule;
            }
            class_1.prototype.out = function () {
                return this.customModule;
            };
            ;
            return class_1;
        }())]);
});
```

**As you can see** in the `main.js` there is a `define(["require", "exports", "angular"], factory);`. But I expect `define(["require", "exports", "angular", "customModule"], factory);`.

If I replace `return this.customModule;` on `main.ts` with `return customModule;` it will exports it right but I think then I not need the constructor. - As you can see the changes on the picture I removed the constructor because it's not needed.

[image: Changes of main.js after removing constructor]

If this problem is solved I can use my modules with TypeScript as I use them with JavaScript <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler has an optimisation, so if you have the below code, something magic happens...

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import * as customModule from 'customModule';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('customFactory', ['customModule', class {
        constructor(
            private customModule
        ) { }

        out() {
            return this.customModule;
        };
    }]);
```

Because the compiler can't see any reference to anything within `customModule`, it optimises away the import.

You can fix it by either using the imported module, or by using a forced import as shown below:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import 'customModule'; // <-- FORCED

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('customFactory', ['customModule', class {
        constructor(
            private customModule
        ) { }

        out() {
            return this.customModule;
        };
    }]);
```